# Can I make a double& with an int

Tags: c++

I wrote this piece of code which works[1], but give me the warning message[2], indeed I want to set the address of an int in a double. I just wonder if it is save to do that with ref (I will not experience weird behaviour).

[2]

> test.cc:10:27: warning: narrowing conversion of 'myint' from 'int' to 'double' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
>    const double &intref{myint};

[1]

```
int main(){    
    int myint{10};
    cout<<"myint: "<<myint<<endl;

    const double &intref{myint};
    cout<<"intref: "<<intref<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What could this possibly do that's not weird?

Comment: `I want to set the address of an int in a double` A reference isn't an address. Even if it was, why do you _think_ you want this? Any attempt to dereference said address would break the language's aliasing rules and therefore invoke undefined behaviour. And for what? What are you trying to do? This is almost certainly an X/Y question, i.e. rather than asking 'How do I do Specific Thing X?', tell us what is the General Thing Y that led you to ask that question. There absolutely must be a better solution that whatever you're trying to do here.

Comment: ...or if you meant you literally want to cast the numerical representation of an `int *` address and store it in a `double` variable, than that is not a valid conversion either, for multiple reasons. There's just no interpretation of this question that makes any sense or gives people a useful basis to answer. You really need to rewrite it to explain your motivation properly.

Answer (score 0):

A `double&` has to refer to a double, and `myint` is not a double. You're actually building a temporary double and constructing a `const double&` to the temporary.

Comment: My problem is that I want to make a vector of reference of int and double, but vector can contain only 1 type right? So I try to put the int in double&... and I wonder if it is safe.

Comment: @cabe Containers cannot contain references, as you would have discovered if you had bothered to try constructing one. If you want to store values of multiple possible types, Google for `variant`, `any`, etc. - which will arrive in C++17 and until then are from the Boost library.